# Ensuring required fields cannot be left empty in Browser library (Robot framework)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

There are 6 forms. On each form, there are 6-7 required inputs(text, date,time, dropdown, radio). How do I test all of these?

1 idea is filling all input except for one and seeing whether it says input required or not when submitting it, and doing this one by one for each input in each form.  But that sounds incredibly time consuming and exhausting.

Is there a better way to do this? I dont know if for loop works here either.